# React github pages leads to 404?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I'm working [in the following repo](https://github.com/kitty-claws/site). I'm trying to deploy what I have at the moment (just an image at the moment) and it leads to a 404. Specified in `package.json` is the value `"homepage": "http://kitty-claws.github.io/site"`. After doing `yarn run deploy` I go to [the url](http://kitty-claws.github.io/site).

I like using yarn so I've been trying to use yarn instead for this project. The documentation uses npm instead. I've also tried doing it with npm to no avail.

There are tonnes of guides all saying the same thing and there are very little instructions so I'm not really sure why this happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure: did you enable github pages on the settings page?

Comment: and sometimes it takes a few minutes (sometimes more) to get published.

Comment: I see it works for me now.

Comment: Yes I changed the source branch in the settings from master and back to gh-pages and that seems to have done it. Added it as answer but feels like a cheat.

Comment: I would delete the question on that basis but perhaps someone else runs into the problem in the future?

Answer (score 0):

The project was already set up to work with Github pages. When I deployed (weeks ago) I went to the area of the settings for Github pages on the repo and thought it was cool that it defaulted to the `gh-pages` branch. Which running `yarn run deploy` creates. After posting this question I decided to change that branch to `master` in case I was being really dumb. Obviously it didn't make a difference so I changed it back to `gh-pages` and now it suddenly does. I assume this action *refreshed* whatever Github was expecting.